# Test Remote Push Notification in Xcode 14 without Apple Silicon/T2 Processor

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, simulator

the new Xcode Version supports testing of remote push notifications in the IOS simulator.

> Simulator now supports remote notifications in iOS 16 when running in macOS 13 on Mac computers with Apple silicon or T2 processors. Simulator supports the Apple Push Notification Service Sandbox environment. Your server can send a remote notification to your app running in that simulator by connecting to the APNS Sandbox (api.sandbox.push.apple.com). Each simulator generates registration tokens unique to the combination of that simulator and the Mac hardware it’s running on. See User Notifications for more information.
>
> Remote Notifications support more features (like Notification Service Extensions) than locally simulated notifications using .apns payload files or the simctl push command.
>
> Device Registration Tokens are of variable length. Tokens in Simulator may be larger than current physical device tokens. Don’t hardcode any specific length or format for these tokens. (60974170)

Did somebody tested if this works also without Silicon/T2 Processor ? For example in a macOS 13 VM ?

And if not, is it possible now in Xcode 14 to test the Notification Service Extension for example with a .apns File (add mutable-content) in a simulator ? (In my test it didnt seemed to work ?)

I also tried to retrieve remote push notification in my simulator in a macOS13 VM..  I got a token, but it didnt worked.. But I'm using firebase.. so don't know if the problem is that I dont have a Apple Silicon/T2 Processor or if the problem is Firebase FCM.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you believe Apple would go out of their way to explicitly mention in their documentation that it's only supported "*on Mac computers with Apple silicon or T2 processors*" if it worked *without* such hardware...? What exactly would you consider a good/complete answer to this question? [ask]

Comment: Because apple did it already in the past to sell new hardware ? They said the same for several other things, which then later were even possible with older hardware.
And the second question was about apns File with "mutable-content".. if this is now also possible with Xcode 14 .. (Test Notification Extension Service)

Comment: @moriax Do you have any success with an .apns file to test Notification Service Extension? Tested with Ventura, XCode 14 and T2 processor but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Saftpresse99 no, sorry.. but if it doesnt work on your mac with T2 processor, it seems that apple doesnt added any capability about extended notification testing with apn files..